# Jquery change background size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, background

I have problem with changing background-size via jQuery. It works when you give only one parameter, but when I give 2 parameter it doesn't work, I need to send via jQuery 2 variables into background-size for width and height.

here is my js code example.

```
var w = 100;
var h = 100;

$("div").css("background-size", w+"px" + h + "px");
```

here is demo

http://jsfiddle.net/Lv4wt75f/

it's just a simple example in real version I need to send 2 parameter that calculate ratio.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because both those parameters need to have a space in between. You simply need one extra space

```
$("div").css("background-size", w+"px " + h + "px");
                                     ^
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv4wt75f/1/)**

**[Syntax Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)**

Answer (score 2):

You need a space between that px.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div").css("background-size", w+"px " + h + "px");
                                     ^ (Space Here)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div").css("background-size": w+"px " + h+"px");
                                     ^ (Space)
```

use :(colon) instead of ,(comma) after background-size